# go言語はさくらやロリポのスタンダードプランでも使える？

Tags: go

go言語は最低限の環境でもつかえるので、さくらやロリポのスタンダードプランでも使える？
PHPのみでしたが、新しく可能な言語がやっと出たのでしょうか？
PYTHONもRUBYもバージョンが古すぎて実質使えないと聞いています。

＞＞＞
Goであれば、Linuxが動くという最低限の環境でも動作するポータブルなバイナリが生成されるので、プロビジョニングの手間がほとんどなく、動作も環境にほとんど依存しません。

エックスサーバーでも動いたそうです。
http://qiita.com/Lio/items/ee24052e6e2ae0f382d9

ただ新しい言語なので日本語の情報がなく、JSの基礎を学んだ程度ではできないでしょうね。

Comment: レンタルサーバ上ではなくローカル環境で実行形式のバイナリ(スタティックリンク)を作成して、運用環境にデプロイするなどしても良さそうですね。

Comment: GOで作ったショッピングカートや問い合わせフォーム、をさくらやロリポのスタンダードプランで使うことはできないのでしょうか

Comment: golang で作成したプログラムだけではなく、データベース(MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)や http サーバ(Apache, etc.)なども利用するということでしょうか。

Comment: いえ簡易なサイト制作程度なのでショッピングカートや問い合わせフォームが実装できるくらいで十分です。
ただショッピングカートやログイン認証などはDB必須ですかね？

Comment: まぁ、Go で開発しなくても、さくらのレンタルショッピングカートや EC-CUBE などを利用しても良いのではないかと(検索すると導入事例が見つかります)。

Comment: せっかくやるならオワコンのPHPよりもgoやpythonを学んだ方がこれからやるなら良いと思ったのですがやはりPHPの牙城は崩れないのですね。

Comment: go言語はさくらやロリポのスタンダードプランでも使えるのですかね？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ロリポップの共用サーバーでは「C言語などによるバイナリ実行ファイルのCGIの設置」が[禁止事項](https://lolipop.jp/terms/prohibition/)に含まれています。
よって、使えません（技術的には動くはずです）。

さくらのレンタルサーバーでは禁止されてはなさそうですね。
技術的にも可能なはずですが[基本仕様](https://help.sakura.ad.jp/hc/ja/articles/206053142--%E3%81%95%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90-%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E4%BB%95%E6%A7%98)に、

> 共用サーバですので、CPUに著しい負荷をかける処理はご遠慮ください。
>   もし、サービス運営の支障をきたす過負荷をサーバに与えた場合、予告無く設定解除など処置をしますのでご注意ください。

とある通り、こういった点は注意が必要でしょう。
また、OS は FreeBSD です。

Comment: GO言語はプラットフォームを選ばないと聞きましたがロリポやさくらで使えるわけではなく使えないと考えるべきなのですね

Comment: やはりPHP一択であることはずっと変わりそうにないですね

Answer (score -3):

Go言語は、C言語の兄弟言語です。ケントンプソンがGoogleと共に作り上げたコンパイル型のプログラミング言語です。よって、C言語に多少オブジェクト指向の知識があれば簡単に理解出来ます。Go言語はケントンプソンがオブジェクト指向の良いところを取り込んでいる面白いというかオブジェクト指向言語ではないけれど、同等以上の事が可能な今後に期待できる言語です。Udemyに動画講座があります。＾＾；
特筆すべきは、CGOという仕組みで、ライブラリやフレームワークの不足に対応するため、C
言語の資産をソースレベルで利用できます。つまりミックスドプログラミングが可能です。